# Copy Datasets - Between different Organizations in GCP

Tags: google-bigquery

we are having a couple of GCP Organizations, Company X in the EU and the other company in the US. I know we can move datasets across different regions.

But is it also possible to move resources across other Organizations?

Comment: When you say Google Account do you mean to say GCP project? Accounts in GCP are not associated with any region. Only resources inside a GCP project are subject to specific regions.

Comment: Assume, Account 1 is owned and maintained by Organization 1 and Account 2 is owned and maintained by organization 2.

Comment: You want to move resources from one organization to another?

Comment: @SakshiGatyan Yes

Comment: Resourses cannot be migrated directly across organizations, however you can move projects. 
Have you considered giving permissions to user/groups/service account to access the resources across organizations?